# mean square integrability

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Given a joint measurable, adapted process $f(t,\omega)$ with $\int_a^b|f(t,\omega)|^2 dt< \infty$ almost surely. The expectation $E[\int_a^b|f(t)|^2dt]$ may not exist.
However, given a process $\int_a^b|f(t,\omega)|^2dt<n$, one can use the monotony of the expectation to conclude $E[\int_a^b|f(t)|^2dt]<E[n]=n$ and using Fubini $E[\int_a^b|f(t)|^2dt]=\int_a^bE[|f(t)|^2]dt<n$.

Now my question is, what is the distinction between two cases. I mean from $\int_a^b|f(t,\omega)|^2 dt< \infty$ I can conclude there exist an $n$ such that $\int_a^b|f(t,\omega)|^2dt<n$, which make the both cases equivalent. Why I can then define the expectation value in the second case and not in the first?

Thank you

Comment: You should cancel the argument $\omega$ four times (each time it appears inside an expectation).

Comment: @Did you are right, it's done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distinction lies between the integral being finite and it being bounded. $X < \infty$ $, \mathbb{P}$-a.s. does not imply that $\exists n \mathrm{\ s.t.\ } X < n$. Consider the function $X(\omega)=e^{w^3}$ which is finite a.s., i.e., $\mathbb{P}(\omega \in \Omega:X< \infty)=1$ (for the Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}$). This doesn't imply that it is integrable.

Also, the theorem you would use (in the bounded case) would be Tonelli's not Fubini's. I believe Fubini's assumes that the integral is defined over the product measure space, while Tonelli's requires only positivity of the integrand.

Comment: I didn't use Fubini in the first case. I used it if the expectation is bounded by n. As the function f is joint measurable and the expectation is bounded by n, it is defined over the product measure space isn't it? Or is there a flaw in my argumentation?

Comment: Just be sure that I understand you correctly. In your example, $X=\infty$ is a Nullset. Therefore X is finite almost surely. However, it is not integrable. If X is bounded, this restriction is more stronger and we can conclude that X is integrable?

Comment: About your second question. Yes that is correct. Bounded is a stronger condition than finite a.s.

Comment: However, bounded is also not sufficient to conclude integrability (unless you are in a finite measure space). The reason we can conclude integrability is because we are in a finite measure space, specifically a probability space. This is precisely what enabled you to write $\mathbb{E}(n) = n \mathbb{P}(\Omega)=n$